# What is the best way to store 10000 lines recoded in an Android app?

Tags: android, memory-management, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

What is the right way to store 10.000 lines of data inside an app? As per my knowledge Android has:

1. Internal memory
2. External memory
3. Stored preferences
4. SQLite database

What is the correct approach?

Comment: I guess you need to specify more, what are the 10000 lines? binary? Hex? Image compressed as Base64? What do you want with these data?

Comment: You forgot one thing it is "Network Storage"

Comment: for storing it you should use SQLite Data Base.

Comment: depends on what you want to do with those

Answer (score 1):

Which one is better depends only on data **usage**. We writes bytes on disk solely for the purpose of reading them back again. The four places you mentioned, all of them eventually write to the filesystem, but offer different API to access the data, and different mechanisms to possibly find the relevant piece of information.

Each choice is a tradeoff, has its own pros and cons, and without knowing what those 10K lines represent, how they are used, how often they are retrieved, and generally the usage patterns, one can't give a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

**SQLite DB** will be the best option for you as you have to store 100 records.

Also if you want you can store the records in a **file** and keep that in your **Assest folder**, after that on installation of application you can copy that file to your **SDCard**. that will also be good option for you.

Comment: Is there any limitation in SQlite data base? Whether this will work in 1.6 OS to Jelly Bean OS? Whether we need to install this DB? or it will be there in all android OS?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is definitely a better alternative than the others

Comment: Why? Please provide a reason, not just your opinion :-)

Comment: Because by using sql lite, you dont need to put all data to memory. Also you dont need to everytime read from external or internal storage. Also by using sql, you can read data more quick then otherways.

Comment: THe main aim of DB is to optimize storage and making resources optimal for retrieval. And the rest is straight forward :)